# This scope lost with inheritance

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

Here is the example code, two files and "classes".

CRUD class with defined methods, the problem occurs with this.modelName, as I set the routes the this context changes with this code:

The question is how, to get the same scope under the CRUD where you have defined the modelName ?

```
server.get('/users/:id', UserRoutes.find);
```

Code:

```
var db = require('../models');

function CRUD(modelName) {
    this.modelName = modelName;
    this.db = db;
}

CRUD.prototype = {

    ping: function (req, res, next) {
        res.json(200, { works: 1 });
    },

    list: function (req, res, next) {

        // FAILS BECAUSE the modelName is undefined
        console.log(this);

        db[this.modelName].findAll()
            .success(function (object) {
                res.json(200, object);
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                res.json(500, { msg: error });
            });
    }
};

module.exports = CRUD;
```

UserRoutes class:

```
var CRUD = require('../utils/CRUD'),
util = require('util');

var UserModel = function() {
    UserModel.super_.apply(this, arguments);
};

util.inherits(UserModel, CRUD);

var userRoutes = new UserModel('User');

module.exports = userRoutes;
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. `console.log(this);` works as expected. And why wouldn't it? Unless you are using `userRoutes.list` as a handler?

Comment: @freakish I think his comment is on the wrong line, should be 2 lines down

Comment: @jcollum Yeah, I've realized that, forgot to delete the comment. :)

Comment: I wish SO wasn't quite so militant about comment edits/deletes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are using `userRoutes.list` as a handler somewhere else, i.e. the context changes. In that case this should be a simple solution:

```
function CRUD(modelName) {
    this.modelName = modelName;
    this.db = db;
    this.list = CRUD.prototype.list.bind(this);
}
```

Note that you won't be able to access "the other `this`" with that solution (`this` will be permamently bound to `CRUD` instance, no matter how `.list` is called).

The other option is to turn `list` into a function generator (which is pretty much the same what `.bind` does, except you can still use `this` from the other context):

```
CRUD.prototype = {
    // some code

    list: function() {
        var that = this;
        return function (req, res, next) {
            console.log(that);

            db[that.modelName].findAll()
                .success(function (object) {
                    res.json(200, object);
                })
                .fail(function (error) {
                    res.json(500, { msg: error });
                });
        }
    }
};
```

and then use `userRoutes.list()` as a handler.

Comment: Currently best answer as solution works with multiple instances !

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing is generally fixed by stowing the right `this` into `_this`. In your list function `this` is the function object, which doesn't have a modelName object.

```
var _this; 

function CRUD(modelName) {
    this.modelName = modelName;
    this.db = db;
    _this = this // <---------------
}

.... 
// call the _this in the outer scope 
db[_this.modelName]
```

Comment: Good answer freezing the scope with declaring variable for old scope seems to be working and only solution in this case.

Comment: Yeah, good answer if you assume that there are no other instances of `CRUD`.

Comment: @freakish kind of a backhanded compliment there; or was it a passive agressive jab?

Comment: @jcollum I didn't mean to offend you. It really is a good answer. There are singletons after all.

Comment: @freakish sorry, I think that means I've been spending too much time on reddit